# Kendo Tabstrip Get tab name on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Hy,this is my tab strip

```
       @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
          .Name("test")
            .Items(tabstrip =>
        {
            tabstrip.Add().Text("")
                .Selected(true)
                .ContentHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: auto;" })
                    .Content("");


        }
        )
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        )
```

And mu select event

```
$("#test .k-tabstrip-items").on("click", "li.k-state-default", function (e) {
        var selectedtab = tab.select();
        alert(selectedtab.text);

    });
```

but the alert will show only the second click when tab change. Please help me

Comment: please to give a minimal code of your markup? also, it is not clear what you js `tab` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you? `var selectedtab = $(this).text();`